# Django_facebook raises KeyError with facebook App_ID

Tags: python, django, facebook, oauth

I've set up a django project to test out: https://github.com/ryanmark/django_facebook_oauth

I've done exactly as the tutorial specified, but strangely, when running manage.py syncdb I get a key error:

```
$ python2.7 manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    import settings
  File "/home/server/webapps/fblogin/myproject/settings.py", line 129, in <module>
    FACEBOOK_APP_ID = os.environ['214xxxx(exactly as on fb dev)xxxx390']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: '2145_______390'
```

(I've blanked out the key here), but it is the full string as exactly copied from facebook developers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this plugin so maybe it's doing something special, but I can't figure why they expect your app_id to be defined within os.environ...

so in your settings just put

```
FACEBOOK_APP_ID = 'YOURAPPIDHERE'
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = 'YOURAPPSECRETHERE'
```

Alternative you could define those values as OS environment variables.  But I don't know what that really gains you over just defining the values.